# stop image jumping out of position when screen size reduced

Tags: css, html

When I reduce screen size after running the code below, the image phone.png and all the text jump out of position. How can I stop this from happening.

css:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #wrapperlp {
        width: 100%;
        height:700px;
        margin-left:13%;
        margin-top:5%;
        background-image:url(https://***/blackbg.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        opacity:1;

    }

    #designbg {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        margin-left: 5%;
        padding-top: 3%;           
    }
```

styling for text

```
    #ad_head {           
        color: #f2852d;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 28%;
        margin-top: -21.5%;
        font-size: 21px;
    }

     #ad_message {
        margin-left: 28%;
        font-size:10px;
        color:white;
        font-weight:normal;
    }
```

style for phone.png image:

```
    #ad_logo {
        height: 500px;
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-top: -42%;

    }

    #logobtm {
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-top: -42%;
    }
</style>
```

Html:

```
<div id="wrapperlp">
    <div id="designbg"><img src="https://*****/image.png" />
       <div id="ad_logo"><img src="https://****phone.png" /></div>

        <div>   
            <div id="ad_head">Text1<br />Text...</div>
            <div id="ad_message">Text2</div>
            <div id="logobtm"><img src="**.png" /></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle of this? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Created: http://jsfiddle.net/vCZy7/2/...where is the text? Damn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `margin-top` in percentages. However, percentages for margins are measured relatively to the window *width*, not the window height!

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#value-def-margin-width

Solution: use another unit to express the margin of the elements in, or use another way to position them on the screen (for instance `top:5%` in combination with `position:absolute`).